# How to update request URL from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: java, http, servlets, request

I am trying to update a URL request from HTTPS protocol to http [and vice versa]. However I am not sure how to set the new request URL that I just created and pass it on to next servlet.

code snippet is as follows, but it doesn't seem to forward it as expected. Only if I can know how to update a request

```
    String url = null;
    if (request.getScheme().equals("http")) {
        url = "https://" + request.getServerName()+":8080"+ request.getContextPath() + request.getRequestURIWithQueryString();

    System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ Remote User " + request.getRemoteUser());
    System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ Scheme " + request.getScheme());
    System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ ServerName " + request.getServerName());
    System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ ContextPath " + request.getContextPath());
    System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ ServletPath " + request.getServletPath());
    System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ URI with QueryString " + request.getRequestURIWithQueryString());

    if (request.getPathInfo() != null) {

        System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ PathInfo " + request.getPathInfo());
        url += request.getPathInfo();
        System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ URL " + url);
    }




   System.out.println ("***************************Handling request for ************************ URL 2 " + url);

  dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);

}
```

Comment: Ever step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Is this custom or are you trying to make this conversion between traditional sites? Traditionally, `https` runs over port `443`, not `8080`. That said, port numbers don't actually matter when it boils down to it, I just wanted to clarify. Also, you should remember that `https` is encrypted and `http` is cleartext.

Comment: `RequestDispatcher#forward(request,response)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Do you want the servlet to treat HTTP when the request is actually HTTPS?